# C# - What can I do to run the scripts in my .bat file, when bat is called using ProcessStartInfo()?

Tags: c#, batch-file, asp.net-core

I have a web application created using .net core 2. In the application, I have a backup feature. When button is clicked, the application will call the bat file with parameters using ProcessStartInfo().

Everything is okay in the development week, I don't encounter any errors and my .bat file is doing everything it is told to do. But when I deployed the project into the production server, it seems almost all of the command inside the .bat file is not working at all.

I have two windows computers. I deployed the project in computer2 in IIS. Then I access the project in my computer1. I developed the project in computer1. Note that the application have web and api projects.

Here is the folder structure of computer2:

```
C:\Project\
       |-- api\
       |-- web\
       |--script\Backup.bat
```

the WEB is calling the API, then API is calling the Backup.bat by:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Project\script\Backup.bat", "param1"));
var process = Process.Start(info);
process.WaitForExit();
```

the following commands inside the Backup.bat is not working:

```
xcopy /S /I C:\data1 C:\backup\data1
SQLCMD -S .\SQLEXPRESS -U root -P root -Q "Backup Database myDatabase To Disk='C:\backup\myDatabase.bak'"
```

but other commands like MOVE, ECHO, MKDIR is working properly.

It only won't work, when called using the web app, but when called from command prompt it is working properly.

Also I made it work by adding START command before xcopy and SQLCMD, sample is: START XCOPY /S /I .... and START SQLCMD ....

but is it possible to make it work without start command? The start command opens new prompt and I don't want that.

My question is, how can I make my .bat file work in production server as it worked in my development's? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _not working_. What is the error?

Comment: Anyway. `start /b` is the option to start an executable without starting a new window.

Comment: @Gerhard, XCOPY and SQLCMD do nothing. Files and folders are not being copied.

Comment: What is the working dir the scripts starts up as in prod?

Comment: Did you try to set the `WorkingDirectory` property?

Comment: What user account is running the script on the server?  Likely not the same one you use on your development box (hopefully).